# How do I get current location using gps in android?

Tags: android

How do I get current location using gps in android?

Comment: See a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905385/getting-the-current-gps-location-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u need android.location classes from android sdk to put in this feature in your android application...

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html

when developing in [app inventor](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com) use sensor components

> http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/learn/reference/components/sensors.html