# How can I get location without internet in android, using only GPS

Tags: android

I want to get location using GPS only. I don't want to use internet and GPRS in this application. My code is below; tell me where I'm wrong in this.

code:

```
package com.getlocation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UseGps extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private String provider;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); /*
                                         * Use the LocationManager class to
                                         * obtain GPS locations
                                         */
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
         Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 61000, 250,
                mlocListener);
    } /* Class My Location Listener */
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();
        String Text = "My current location is: " + "Latitude = "
                + loc.getLatitude() + "Longitude = " + loc.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        Log.d("TAG", "Starting..");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}/* End of Class MyLocationListener */
}/* End of UseGps Activity */
```

Comment: Not downvoting. Here is a similar post with an accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905385/getting-the-current-gps-location-on-android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this for only GPS Provider, it does not need GPRS.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

You need to put the permission in manifest file.

Comment: Yes GPS is satellite based and does not require internet to work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an internet connection to run GPS system in your mobile. GPS time synchronization does not require an Internet connection. But if you want to show the current location on google map, you may require internet connection.

Coming to you code everything looks fine for me.

Try this code in your activity.

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LocationListener mlocListener = new YourLocationListener(getApplicationContext(), mobileNo, deviceId);
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,mlocListener);
```

and include this in androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
```

Comment: @Sam_k can i get current latitute and logitute without internet connection?

Comment: @PintuCorna You have to use GPS Provide for that