# Android get current position

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I want to know how to locate a position in android device using GPS without 
internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special really required for this. Here is the exact same question.

[How can I get location without internet in android, using only GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013521/how-can-i-get-location-without-internet-in-android-i-wnat-to-know-location-only)